# Self reference loop MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
    Parenttbl
ID   Name   ParentID
---------------------
1    Mary    Null
2    Jane    1
3    Jenny   2
4    Jessa   3
```

I wanted to create a query that will loop from child to parent. For example if I give number 4 as `ID` it will return `3`, `2` , `1`, `Null` (from `Jessa` to `Mary`) until it found out that `ParentID` is `Null`. So far I have this query:

```
SELECT fc2.ID
FROM Parenttbl as fc1
LEFT JOIN Parenttbl as fc2
ON fc1.ParentID = fc2.ID
WHERE fc1.ID = 6
```

I'm planning to use a `while` loop. How can I do that?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at recursive query using CTE: (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I do that?" You know how to write a while loop, right? Make an attempt at actually accomplishing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH Common Table Expressions

```
WITH Hierarchy AS ( 
    SELECT ID,ParentID
    FROM People
    WHERE ID = 4 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT p.ID, p.ParentID 
    FROM People p
    JOIN Hierarchy h ON h.ParentID = p.ID 
) 
SELECT ID FROM Hierarchy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Recursive Query.  Something like this:

```
WITH ParentOf (parentid, name, id, parentlevel)
AS
(
-- Anchor query
    SELECT parentid, name, id, 1 as parentLevel
    FROM parenttbl
    WHERE parenttbl.id = 4
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive query
    SELECT p.parentid, p.name, p.id, parentlevel +1  
    FROM parenttbl p
    INNER JOIN ParentOf  
        ON p.Id = ParentOf.parentid
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ParentId, name, id, parentlevel
FROM ParentOf;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/361c2/23)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `Recursive CTE` over any kind of *loops* or *cursor* approach

```
with cte as
(
    select * from parenttbl
    where id = 4
    union all
    select p.* from parenttbl p 
    inner join cte c on p.id <= c.parentid
) 
select id, name, parentid from cte
group by id, name, parentid
```